# What's the best strategy to count the eggs in the jar?

Tags: estimation

It's Easter time, and in my workplace we have a "Count the eggs in the jar!" kind of game.

[image]

What would be the best mathematical strategy to get as close as possible to the correct count?

**Update:** The contest has ended, the number of eggs is (Hover over the box below)

> 154

Comment: I like the second tag !!

Comment: a) Open the jar and count - b) weigh (requires an empty jar and identical egg to compare) - c) find out what others guess and make a guess in the largest gap in the reasonable range (if you don't know what others guess, assume they guess round numbers)

Comment: @Amr In all fairness, I have no clue what estimation theory is. It had "estimation" in it, so I thought it's relevant.

Comment: 157. Give or take...

Comment: If the jar were near my desk, the number would at least be (almost strictly) decreasing :)

Comment: @Jakob I ended up making calculations and estimations based on the photo and size of each egg. I ended up with 149. I answered 153

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out what everyone else guessed and [average their guesses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom_of_the_crowd).

Comment: This is a genius idea.

Answer (score 2):

I made some calculations, here's the draft from my notepad

```
Egg: 3cm x 2.3cm (8.3ml)
Jar: (pi*8.5cm^2) x 10cm (2269ml)
Filled volume: 1868.5ml (estimate)
Normalized to the packing efficiency (66.5%) : 1242.5ml

1242.5/8.3 = 149.7 eggs
```

I wasn't off by much.